# How to remove white lines at the bottom of NavigationBar by transition from large titles to small titles

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigationbar, preferslargetitles

[image]Is there a way to do the transition cleaner, without these white lines?

In rootView I've:

```
   navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

and in Detailview:

```
   navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

In AppDelegate:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .BlackNav
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]


        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT:

Solved: the lines disappear if you don't define UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
 //UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
 UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: Please add the platform tag, is this Android or iOS?

Comment: @David: iOS, Swift